# TFS/Azure Devops Server - Domain Migration - How to handle former staff that don't have accounts in the new domain

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I'm in the process of planning a migration of Azure Devops Server (version 17.143.28912.1, AzureDevOps2019.0.1) from one domain to another. I'm seeking guidance on how to handle users that have Identities in the old domain, but for various reasons (former staff, deceased, etc.) will never have an account in the new domain. What should be done with those Identities?

I've read through the domain migration questions here and the [Microsoft guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-across-domains?view=azure-devops-2022) on the migration process. However I am not seeing related guidance.

Comment: For the former staff account, do you mean that you need to remove the account when changing to new domain or you need to use the account in the new domain to inherit the permissions,work items ...  of the old account?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT, I want to maintain the assignment field values (any "person" field values) after the migration. Those accounts will never have a new-domain account or log in, obviously.  So I don't need to remove it. Just keep the values in the work items. Thanks!

Comment: Azure DevOps (aka TFS) maintains identities independent of the domain. I believe (but I'm not 100% sure) the old identities will remain in Azure DevOps and will be used for history but can't be used for access because they don't exist in the new domain. Some sources that may help: ["Identities and Work Item Tracking in TFS 2015"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/identities-and-work-item-tracking-in-tfs-2015/), ["Migrating TFS to a new data center"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/migrating-tfs-to-a-new-data-center/).

Comment: We completed our domain migration last week. Ultimately, "former staff" are just left as-is. TFS will remember their values used in identity fields (Assigned To, etc). However if you subsequently try to edit a record with that now-unknown identity, it will not save without changing to a known identity value. For us, this is okay for historic data. For any work items still open, it probably needed to be updated anyway.

Comment: Another note on the migration, a couple identities did not migrate correctly. Reason 1: One identity in the new domain was already known to TFS. Reason 2: Changed the wrong (very similar) Identity to the desired new one, and subsequently could not migrated the right one. 

To remedy this, I used a couple queries, opened them in Excel, and mass updated the values. Worked great.